# How to get response without entering credentials in angular

Tags: angular, rest, spring-boot

I am working on angular, spring boot application. Where I need to communicate with another application for that I need to have some token.

To get that token, I have an URL if hit the URL it will prompt for username, pwd once I enter them and submit it will validate and gives me response.

But, the problem is I don't want that popup to enter credentials, I have to do it programatically. How to achieve this, I was trying to use Javafx but my organization is not allowing to open that URL in javafx window of course I don't want that pop up. Can I mimic that browser behavior in my app?

Comment: You can try passing user name and pwd in the request itself.

Comment: @Abdu Manaz, that I 've already tried... but no use...  we don't know how it was working in other application. We don't have scope to see that implementation.